# Que signifie l'expression "que ça fume" dans ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, expressions, littérature

Que signifie l'expression "**que ça fume**" dans ce contexte ? Je sais que d'habitude l'expression veut dire "éprouver une grande colère". Mais Céline écrit dans *Casse-pipe* (1949) :

"Le brigadier toute langue dehors il est tout de
même parvenu à recopier mon nom.

-Planton! hop! sautez, choléra! **que ça fume** et
hop! Que le Parisien est arrivé! Au margis tout de
suite, l’engagé! Compris?"

Il me semble que l'expression n'a pas sons sens usuel ici. On trouve dans https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/79381 la suggestion qu'il s'agit, dans ce cas, d'un "appel à se presser".

Si l'interprétation est juste, qu'est-ce qu'il y a, dans "**fumer**",
qui lui permet, à l'auteur, de dériver le sens originel de colère au sens employé dans le texte, de hâte ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Une première interprétation de l'expression employée par Céline :

- « Ça va fumer » a le même sens que « ça va barder » ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fumer)).  Et « Que ça barde/que ça chauffe »  signifie : *Je vais m'énerver* (c'est une menace, ça exprime la colère du brigadier).

2. On peut aussi choisir une interprétation plus « littérale » : la fumée évoque le feu, donc la chaleur. Le mouvement des molécules produit de la chaleur et plus les molécules se déplacent rapidement, plus elles produisent de la chaleur.

- Que ça fume → que ça chauffe → que ça s'agite.

C'est ainsi que le brigadier exhorte le planton à s'agiter.

À noter que si autant « que ça barde » et « que ça chauffe » sont des expressions courantes, « que ça fume » ne l'est pas. Personnellement je ne l'ai jamais lu/entendu que chez Céline.